# How to find a plane spanned by two non-linear vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

I have 4 points - $A(0, 0, 1)$, $B(2, 0, -1)$, $C(-1, 0, 2)$ and $D(1, -1, -2)$. I have to find the plane defined by the lines $AB$ and $CD$.

I started by comptuing the vectors $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{CD}$ and I got that $\vec{AB} = (2, 0, -2)$ and that $\vec{CD}= (2, -1, -4)$. Then I computed the vector product for $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$, which came out as $2 \vec i + 4 \vec j - 2 \vec k$. So the normal of the plane should be $(2, 4, -2)$ and those are $A$, $B$ and $C$ coefficients in the plane equation, which goes as such: $ax + by + cz + d = 0$. I don't understand how will I get the $d$ in the plane equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get $D$, plug in a point on the plane i.e any one of $A,B,C$ or $D$. Also, you should use a different $D$ in your plane equation to not confuse things.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? The thing is, I don't have any point on the plane (I just have the plane's direction vector, also refferd to as it's normal).

Comment: Yes you do! $A,B,C,D$ are all on your plane.

Comment: Yes, I understand that $A, B, C$ and $D$ are on my plane. However, I don't have the $D$ (the number we use to compute the plane's distance from the origin) and I $A, B, C$ are the coordinates of my normal. I could express the plane in it's segment form (where $D$ would be an unkwnown, alongside $x, y$ and $z$) and then I'd have 3 points. I don't seem to really get this, I am sorry; could you elaborate further?

Comment: You know what $a,b$ and $c$ are. Now, where $x,y,z$ is, plug in any of the points $A,B,C$ or $D$ and you will get $d$.

Comment: Oooooh I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can also write
$$\vec{x}=\vec{OA}+s\vec{AB}+t\vec{AD}$$
this gives $$[x,y,z]=[0,0,1]+s[2,0,-2]+t[1,-1,-3]$$ where $s,t$ are real numbers